# Switching a conditional case in php

Tags: php

I use javascript to send cases to and ajax function. The cases are taken from the link id. For example, if user clicked this link:
`<a id="answer-yes-123">click this</a>`
The javascript will split the id to 3 part, and send the middle part "yes" to ajax as a case. For most cases, when ajax receives the case, if yes do this if no do that.

```
switch ($case) {
    case 'yes' :
        $assignment->add();
        break;
    case 'no' :
        $assignment->remove();
        break;
```

There's one exception-- a numerical case. If the middle part of the link is a number, I don't know how to make the switching statement. There are potentially unlimited different numbers, I can't make each of them a case, How to make a condition like `if(is_int($case))` to work as a case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `switch` `default:` case, you can test `is_int()`:

```
switch ($case) {
    case 'yes' :
        $assignment->add();
        break;
    case 'no' :
        $assignment->remove();
        break;
    default:
        // Determine the numeric value however you need to 
        // is_int(), is_numeric(), preg_match(), whatever...
        if (is_int($case)) {
           // numeric stuff
        }
}
```

This is a little strange logically, because `default:` is typically used for the *do this if nothing else is met* condition. In your case though, if you don't need to further divide the numeric case much it works.  Just be sure to comment it clearly in your code so you remember why you did it when you look back on it in six months.

#### Update after comments:

Since you already used the `default:`, I believe you can actually use an expression inside a `case`. This warrants even clearer commenting since it is not a common practice and goes kind of against the purpose of a `switch`:

```
switch ($case) {
    case 'yes' :
        $assignment->add();
        break;
    case 'no' :
        $assignment->remove();
        break;
    // This actually works, but is highly weird. 
    // One of those things I can't believe PHP allows.
    // is_int(), is_numeric(), preg_match(), whatever... 
    case is_int($case):
        // Numeric stuff
        break;
    default:
        // default stuff
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I already used up the default for something else.

Comment: @Jenny See above. You actually can use the expression inside the `case`.

Answer (score 2):

Write the if-statement around the switch.

Something like this comes to my mind:

```
if (is_int($case)) {
   // ...
} else {
    switch ($case) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Michael Berkowski's answer is perfect, but if don't want to use default case like this that could work also:

```
switch (preg_replace('/^[0-9]*$/','numeric',$case)) {
case 'yes' :
    $assignment->add();
    break;
case 'no' :
    $assignment->remove();
    break;
case 'numeric' :
    $assignment->remove();
    break;
default:
    //...
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `is_numeric`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

```
if (is_numeric($case)) {
   // ...
} else {
    switch ($case) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem he has. He wants to use if-statements inside the switch-case.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Didn't know not holding his hand warranted a downvote.  Thanks pal.

Comment: @kdg123 I didn't down vote, that's one thing I never do on this site, whatever the answer is, the helper spent time and tried to help. It goes against my belief if I down vote people who want to help.